# Are civilian/GA pilots expected to "see and avoid" fast military jets in VMC?

Tags: airspace, military, see-and-avoid, vmc

I don't know if this also applies to the U.S. or just to Europe, but in Europe the civilian airspace is frequently used by military jets. On numerous occasions I've seen F-16's and other fighter jets using the same airspace I was flying in (both controlled and uncontrolled)

According to the regulations, we should "see and avoid" other traffic but **does that rule apply when encountering these fast military jets**? Let's face it: there's no way you can see and avoid a fighter jet approaching at +400kts.

Are there specific regulations covering this? Who's at fault when a midair collision occurs? (sadly it has happened in the past)

**EDIT**

It happened again last week: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015_Moncks_Corner_mid-air_collision

How can something like this happen? Don't F16's have their own radar?

Comment: Below 10,000MSL there is a speed limit of 250kts anyway with the exception of Military Operating Areas (MOA) that are depicted on the charts. http://www.cfinotebook.net/notebook/airspace/military-operating-area.html Makes me feel better anyway since I fly small airplanes usually below 10k

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qLVtstYAZLY

Comment: @p1l0t Actually that speed limit is waived for military aircraft on MTR's (see the 2nd excerpt in my answer below).

Comment: Yes I'm aware of this. I did forget to mention though.

Comment: @Lnafziger - as well as being waived for certain aircraft which are unsafe to fly below 250 kts for long periods, such as the T-38

Comment: @SSumner: Why is it unsafe?  Do they really have a stall speed greater than 250kts?

Comment: @Sean see this Q&A: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/34480/what-aircraft-fly-faster-than-250-knots-indicated-airspeed-under-10-000-feet-for (essentially lack of control below 250 kts)

Answer (score 14):

It is both parties responsibility to see-and-avoid, but it does help to know where you are more likely to find high speed military activity and high performance maneuvering to aid you in seeing and avoiding.

Military operations in the US are typically confined to military training routes (MTR), military operations areas (MOA), restricted airspace and prohibited airspace.

The MTRs are low altitude, high speed routes and are charted on sectional charts so you know to be extra vigilant around them or to just avoid them altogether.

Military operation areas or MOAs are charted and are big boxes with ceiling and floor altitudes.  GA aircraft can query ATC if these are active and in any case they can fly into them.  If a GA aircraft penetrates and active MOA, the military activity is typically stopped until you leave.  General rule of thumb is to just not go there.

Restricted areas are only accessible to you when cold, so there will not be military activity there if you allowed to be there.

Prohibited airspace may not have military activity before you show up, but certainly will after you do, and you might get to watch an F16 attempt slow flight and form up on your wing.  Remember your intercept procedures for this one.

Any military activity outside of this will generally be typical enroute flying at altitude.  You will occasionally hear ATC coordinating mid-air refueling but that won't be something you have to worry about.

Comment: This is certainly not the case in Belgium. Our home was located in G-airspace and we regularly saw F-16s buzzing overhead at 500ft AGL. It's definitely not a military training route.

Comment: @PhilippeLeybaert Yeah, the U.S. has a lot more wide open space in which the military can practice than most Western European countries, especially Belgium. If you look at sectionals of almost any state in the Western or Central U.S., there are MOAs (and/or restricted areas) everywhere.

Comment: Yeah, there's a big one down south of Abilene, called the Brownwood MOA, where most of the guys stationed in Texas go to play. It's no more than an hour's cruise time from JB San Antonio, NAS-JRB Ft Worth and Dyess AFB.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, both pilots are required to see and avoid at all times when operating in VMC conditions.  Typically the military pilots have radar used to pickup other aircraft that can help them, but ultimately it still comes down to looking outside.

We have military training routes charted here in the US that are used by military aircraft when operating at high speeds, and pilot should be especially vigilant when operating in the vicinity of one of these routes.  Use all available information: Get flight following and  contact the frequency on the chart for current operational information, and above all keep an eye out for them!

---

The [Aeronautical Chart Users Guide](https://aeronav.faa.gov/content/aeronav/online/pdf_files/Chart_Users_Guide_11thEd.pdf) shows an example of how they chart it on VFR Charts:

> Military Training Routes (MTRs) are shown on  Sectionals and TACs.
>   They are identified by the route  designator: [image: MTR example]. Route
>   designators  are shown in solid black on the route centerline, 
>   positioned along the route for continuity. The designator  IR or VR is
>   not repeated when two or more routes  are established over the same
>   airspace, e.g., IR201- 205-227. Routes numbered 001 to 099 are shown
>   as  IR1 or VR99, eliminating the initial zeros. Direction of  flight
>   along the route is indicated by small arrowheads  adjacent to and in
>   conjunction with each route  designator.
>
> The following note appears on Sectionals and TACs  covering the
>   conterminous United States.
>
> [image: MTR Warning]
>
> There are IFR (IR) and VFR (VR) routes as follows:  Route
>   identification: a. Routes at or below 1500’ AGL (with no segment 
>   above 1500’) are identified by four-digit numbers;  e.g., VR1007, etc.
>   These routes are generally  developed for flight under Visual Flight
>   Rules. b. Routes above 1500’ AGL (some segments of  these routes may
>   be below 1500’) are identified by  three or fewer digit numbers; e.g.,
>   IR21, VR302,  etc. These routes are developed for flight under 
>   Instrument Flight Rules.
>
> MTRs can vary in width from 4 to 16 miles. Detailed  route width
>   information is available in the Flight  Information Publication (FLIP)
>   AP/1B (a DoD  publication), or in the Digital Aeronautical Chart 
>   Supplement (DACS) produced by AeroNav Products. Special Military
>   Activity areas are indicated on the  Sectionals by a boxed note in
>   black type. The note  contains radio frequency information for
>   obtaining area  activity status.
>
> [image: MTR Frequency Box]

On IFR charts, they are similar:

> MILITARY TRAINING ROUTES (MTRs)
>
> Military Training Routes (MTRs) are routes established  for the
>   conduct of low-altitude, high-speed military flight  training
>   (generally below 10,000 feet MSL at airspeeds  in excess of 250 knots
>   Indicated Air Speed). These  routes are depicted in brown on Enroute
>   Low Altitude  Charts, and are not shown on inset charts or on IFR 
>   Enroute High Altitude Charts. Enroute Low Altitude  Charts depict all
>   IR (IFR Military Training Route) and VR  (VFR Military Training Route)
>   routes, except those VRs  that are entirely at or below 1,500 feet
>   AGL. Military Training Routes are identified by designators  (IR-107,
>   VR-134) which are shown in brown on the  route centerline. Arrows are
>   shown to indicate the  direction of flight along the route. The width
>   of the route  determines the width of the line that is plotted on the 
>   chart:
>
> Route segments with a width of 5 NM or less, both  sides of the
>   centerline, are shown by a .02” line.
>
> Route segments with a width greater than 5 NM, either  or both sides
>   of the centerline, are shown by a .035”  line.
>
> MTRs for particular chart pairs (ex. L1/2, etc.) are  alphabetically,
>   then numerically tabulated. The  tabulation includes MTR type and
>   unique ident and  altitude range.

---

As far as who is at fault, it is a joint responsibility so everybody would be in most cases.

Comment: There's no way you can see and avoid a fighter jet at speed.

Comment: Sell your 172 and buy a war-surplus F-4.

Comment: Quite the opposite, I regularly am flying directly at another jet with a closing speed of greater than 900 KTS and can see them quite well.  Not for very long, but I can see them.  :)

Comment: @Lnafziger I'm sure you can, but you probably knew where to look.

Comment: @PhilippeLeybaert Sometimes, but not always!

Comment: @Lnafziger; fighter jets (as opposed to other jets) are usually painted in a way to.. well.. make them hard to see, aren't they?

Comment: @roe Yes they are, but that doesn't change the regulations, unfortunately.....

Comment: Lo these many years ago, the US Navy had a poster up for flight safety. It stated, " At today's jet speeds, the time involved from seeing an oncoming aircraft to the time the pilots can almost react is short."